# Creating “CSS” with “PHP”

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to create inline CSS using PHP Not sure why it is not working
I need to be to write the css based on the data coming from my database This was a test script to see if I could put php between style tags and create css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
*{padding-right: 0px; PADDING-left: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin: 0px; padding-top: 0px;}

<?php
echo "<br/>";
echo '.button { ';
echo "<br/>";
echo 'background-color: green;';
echo "<br/>";
echo 'border: none;';
echo "<br/>";
echo 'color: white;';
echo "<br/>";
echo 'padding: 15px 32px;';
echo "<br/>";
echo 'text-align: center;';
echo "<br/>";
echo 'text-decoration: none;';
echo "<br/>";
echo 'display: inline-block;';
echo "<br/>";
echo 'font-size: 16px;';
echo "<br/>";
echo 'margin: 4px 2px;';
echo "<br/>";
echo 'cursor: pointer;';
echo "<br/>";
echo '} ';
echo "<br/>";
?>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>CSS Buttons</h2>

<button>Default Button</button>
<a href="#" class="button">Link Button</a>
<button class="button">Button</button>
<input type="button" class="button" value="Input Button">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can replace `*{padding-right: 0px; PADDING-left: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin: 0px; padding-top: 0px;}` with `*{padding:0;margin:0;}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating invalid CSS by putting all those `<br/>` tags in the CSS. Use `echo "\n";` instead, to put actual newlines. Or just leave them out -- CSS doesn't care if the styles are on the same line or not.

Comment: Here is what the working code looks like now: